# Приоритет между соединениями tcp

Tags: tcp-ip

Объясните пожалуйста: как работает определение того какое соединение TCP будет сейчас отправлять пакет? Ну то есть вот есть обычный сокет и несколько соединений у каждого из которых две очереди для отправки и приёма пакетов. Как сокет понимает кому дать возможность отправить пакет? Моё предположение: в сокете есть очередь и пакеты отправляют сразу все соединения которым это нужно. А сокет потом разберётся. Я прав? Также ещё один вопрос насколько быстро работает копирование пакетов?

Comment: У каждого соединения свой сокет.

Comment: А как тогда ОС решает какой сокет сейчас будет отправлять данные?

Comment: У всех функций отправки данных сокет фигуриует в качестве аргумента.

Comment: Возможно [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000457/7286264) поможет вам зацепиться за что-либо там и раскрутить интерсующую вас тему. (откровенно говоря, лезть в сорсы и досконально разбираться с дисциплиной выбора пакета для передачи драйверу устойства совершенно не хочется)

Comment: Спасибо! За ответ.